# How to call a function that uses the state (which is set by another function) and updates state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions one that fetches data from an api and updates state according to that data, and a function that itterates over the data in the state and updates the state with the new data.

My problem is that i cant update the state in the second function. And i dont know where i have to call this function in order for it to be called after the first function and to use the data thats in the state.

```
export default class Cases extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cases: [],
            photos: [],
        };

        this.addPhotos = this.addPhotos.bind(this);
        this.getCases = this.getCases.bind(this);
        this.renderCases = this.renderCases.bind(this);
    }

    getCases() {
        axios
            .get('/cases/api')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    cases: response.data.cases,
                    photos: response.data.photos,
                });
                console.log(this.state.cases);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
    }

    addPhotos() {
        const newCases = this.state.cases.map(({ photo_id, ...rest }) => {
            const obj = { ...rest };
            this.state.photos.find(data => {
                if (data.id === photo_id) {
                    obj.file = data.file;
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return obj;
        });

        console.log(this.state.cases);

        this.setState({
          'cases' : newCases
        });

    }

    renderCases() {
        this.addPhotos();
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getCases();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              {this.renderCases()}
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is what i now have

Where should i call the addPhotos function so it can update the state and still use the existing state data from the getCases function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do i not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first thing's first. The lifecycle method componentWillMount() is soon to be deprecated and is considered unsafe to use. You should be using componentDidMount().

As far as using the updated state in your addPhotos function, you can pass setState a callback function. A seemingly simple solution would be to just pass the addPhotos function as a callback into the setState being called in your getCases function.

```
 getCases() {
        axios
            .get('/cases/api')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    cases: response.data.cases,
                    photos: response.data.photos,
                }, this.addPhotos);
                console.log(this.state.cases);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
    }
```

Another solution would be to call addPhotos() from componentDidUpdate instead.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Just some additional background information from the React docs.

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

Comment: Apparently, addPhotos should be this.addPhotos, and this.addPhotos itself has issues

Comment: this.setState({
                    cases: response.data.cases,
                    photos: response.data.photos,
                }, this.addPhotos); this works

Comment: Correct, should be this.addPhotos. Edited answer to reflect this. Not really here to comment on the rest of the code. My answer is only intended to address his particular question.

Answer (score 1):

Added some refactoring to your code, should work ok now, read comments for details

```js
export default class Cases extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cases: [],
      photos: [],
    };

    this.addPhotos = this.addPhotos.bind(this);
    this.getCases = this.getCases.bind(this);
    this.renderCases = this.renderCases.bind(this);
  }

  getCases() {
    axios
      .get('/cases/api')
      .then(this.addPhotos) // don't need to set state, pass data to consumer function
      .catch(console.error); // catch always gives error, don't need to check with if statement
  }

  addPhotos(response) {
    const cases = response.data.cases // extract values
    const photos = response.data.photos // extract values
    
    // your .map iterator has O^2 complexity (run each item of cases on each item of photos)
    // this new .map iterator has O complexity (run each item of cases)
    const newCases = cases.map(({ photo_id, ...rest }) => {
      const obj = {...rest};
      const data = photos.find(item => item.id === photo_id);
      if (data) {
        obj.file = data.file
      }
      return obj;
    });

    this.setState({
      cases: newCases,
      photos
    });

  }

  componentDidMount() { // better use didMount
    this.getCases();
  }


  render() {
    return (<div />)
  }
}
```